# Load UIViewController from the separate nib file in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I had take one ViewController with separate nib file. and my initial root viewcontroller is set in the storyBoard. Now the problem is that when I push to this controller the  View hireachy methods are not being called (ViewDidLoad , ViewWillApper , etc)..

**Code** (View is loaded but methods are not calling)

```
var viewController = UIViewController(nibName: "OfferDetailViewController", bundle: nil) as OfferDetailViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
```

The same thing if i do with the storyboard its working fine.

```
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("offer") as OfferDetailViewController     
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
```

**Problem** : With storyboard View hierarchy methods are calling but not with the separate nib file?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
var viewController = OfferDetailViewController(nibName: "OfferDetailViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: @SidShah it's the obvious problem What I have found in your code. you need init an `OfferDetailViewController ` rather than an `UIViewController`. You may need fix this before you fix the problem

Comment: In My case this is take 1.5 second to load ,any solution for this problem?? Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to push from Xib to UIViewController ?

Answer (score 22):

Here is a nice generic approach...

```
extension UIViewController {
    class func loadFromNib<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
         return T(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    }
}

let vc : OfferDetailViewController = OfferDetailViewController.loadFromNib()
```

Comment: doesn't compile. change className() to "String(describing: self)"

Comment: @AaronBratcher Thanks. I wrote another extension from my project. Updated it.

Answer (score 12):

solution with **type casting**:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func initFromNib() -> Self {
        func instanceFromNib<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
            return T(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
        }
        return instanceFromNib()
    }
}
```

enjoyment:

```
let testVC = TestVC.initFromNib()
testVC.someCustomParam = "someValue"
```