# Load viewcontroller with nib using generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uiviewcontroller, nib

Currently to load viewcontroller with same nibname I use code as follows

```
let recommendationVC : RecommendationVC = RecommendationVC(nibName: "RecommendationVC", bundle: nil)
```

I feel specifying nibname is unncessary as it is same as controller name. So i decided to use generics and infer type and nib name using generics

```
protocol NibIdentifiable {
    static var nibNameIdentifier: String { get }
}

// MARK: - Indentifies each storyboard from its classname.
extension NibIdentifiable where Self: UIViewController {
    static var nibNameIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
extension UIViewController :NibIdentifiable
{

}

extension UIViewController {
    func instantiate<Controller: UIViewController>(_: Controller.Type) -> Controller where Controller: NibIdentifiable {

        guard let controller = Self(nibName:Controller.nibNameIdentifier,bundle:nil) as? Controller else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(Controller.nibNameIdentifier)")
        }

        return controller
    }
}
```

But on trying to create a VC instance,

```
 let recommendationVC :RecommendationVC = UIViewController.instantiate()
```

receiving error 
**Generic parameter 'Controller' could not be inferred**

What is wrong in this approach?

Comment: let recommendationVC :RecommendationVC = RecommendationVC.instantiate()

try like this

Comment: @KonstantinKryzhanovsky I have tried that. Facing same issue

Comment: When the nib name is the same as the class name you don't even have to specify it. Just doing `let recommendationVC = RecommendationVC()` should work fine.

Comment: You can check out my answer here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44215068/919545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Rec : UIViewController  {
    let r : String = "1231231"
}

protocol NibIdentifiable {
    static var nibNameIdentifier: String { get }
}

// MARK: - Indentifies each storyboard from its classname.
extension NibIdentifiable where Self: UIViewController {
    static var nibNameIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    static func instantiate() -> Self {

        guard let controller = Self(nibName:Self.nibNameIdentifier,bundle:nil) as? Self else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(Self.nibNameIdentifier)")
        }

        return controller
    }

}

extension UIViewController : NibIdentifiable {
}

let x : Rec = Rec.instantiate()
```

This must works.

In my case i use some Storyboardable protocol. and initiate Controller from specific storyboard.

Answer (score 9):

Add the extension for UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func instantiateFromNib() -> Self {
        func instantiateFromNib<T: UIViewController>(_ viewType: T.Type) -> T {
            return T.init(nibName: String(describing: T.self), bundle: nil)
        }

        return instantiateFromNib(self)
    }
}
```

and then use just like that

> let myViewController = MyViewController.instantiateFromNib()

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me, although I did not go with the inner function; I just straight up called `return self.init(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil);`